# React Hooks: contentEditable not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function transformation(data) {
  data = data + "it works";
  return data;
}

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const handleChanges = (event) => {
    setValue(event.currentTarget.innerHTML);
  };
  return (
    <div
      contentEditable
      onChange={handleChanges}
      html={transformation(value)}
    />
  );
}
```

Why isn't onChange working whenever something is written in the div? I cannot launch the function "transformation".  works fine... It seem to be an issue with contentEditable. I require this to be done with a hook.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `react-contenteditable` component which I think will do what you are looking for. The following code is your app with it implemented:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ContentEditable from "react-contenteditable";
import "./styles.css";

function transformation(data) {
  const test = `${data} It works`;
  return test;
}

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChanges = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <ContentEditable
      style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}
      innerRef={this.contentEditable}
      onChange={handleChanges}
      html={transformation(value)}
    />
  );
}
```

You can have a play around on the following: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-breeze-6rmih?file=/src/App.js:0-549

And you can read the component's documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable

Comment: You might wanna fix your `transformation` funciton not to append to what's already there. But other than that + 1

Comment: Is there a way without this dependency, what's the trick / issue with react when it comes to contentEditable

Comment: @Train oh for sure, I was just leaving it there as I wasn't sure on the OPs original purpose for it if I am honest.

Comment: @Mehdy If you take a look at the dependency src code you'll be able to see what the author did to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The onChange attribute is only applicable to Form Field elements, such as input, select, textarea etc. Just change your div to any form element and it should work fine. :-)

Comment: I need to emulate a textarea for styling unfortunatly a form field element won't do it

Answer (score 1):

I think that the correct answer is in this link:
[how-to-listen-for-changes-in-a-contenteditable-element-in-react](https://thewebdev.info/2021/09/19/how-to-listen-for-changes-in-a-contenteditable-element-in-react/)
since it does not use an external package.

example:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
   return(
      <div contentEditable
          onInput={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.textContent)}>
         Text inside div
      </div>
);
}
```

Comment: hm, for some reason this causes typing work backwards for me ("Test" → "tseT")